# Making multiple variables equal to multiple values from a list

Tags: python, python-3.8

Is there a way I can use something like this:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In order to get the values:

```
a = 1
b = [2, 3]
c = [4, 5]
```

Comment: a, b, c = 1, [2, 3], [4, 5]

Comment: Python lets you do `a, *b, c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, which sets `b` to `[2,3,4]`.  I don't believe there is any way to say "I want this variable to be two elements from the list" except to put two variables on the left side of the equal sign, and then make a list out of them separately.

Comment: no, you can't. YOu can do `a, *x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; b=x[:2];c=x[2:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break up existing data as needed:

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a,b,c = data[0],data[1:3],data[3:]
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3]
>>> c
[4, 5]
```